# How to keep track of Array index in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, angularjs

Very new to Angularjs. So I have some JSON files that I am reading into my webpage that contain and array of objects that are cars. What I am trying to do is have my "button" when pressed alert me to the data specific to that button.

The ng-repeat is running 8 times so that is the length of the array, but in angularJs i'm not sure how to basically store the array index for each time the ng-repeat passes in my button function.

This is my a snippet of my .html:

```
    <div class="carTable table-responsive text-center" ng-controller="ButtonController" >
    <table class="table specTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Make</th>
                <th>Model</th>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Color</th>
                <th>Milage</th>
                <th>Doors</th>
                <th class="reserve">Horsepower</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th class="reserve"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="cars in car | orderBy:'year'">
                <td>{{cars.year}}</td>
                <td>{{cars.model}}</td>
                <td>{{cars.make}}</td>
                <td>{{cars.color}}</td>
                <td>{{cars.mileage | number}}</td>
                <td>{{cars.doors}}</td>
                <td>{{cars.horsepower}}</td>
                <td>{{cars.price | number}}</td>
                <td><div class="panel panel-default"><a  href="" ng-click="buttonPress()">Reserve</a></div></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The portion in question is at the bottom where I have a Reserve "button"

I'm leaving out my JSON files, works properly there. I'm just not sure how to keep track of the array index as the ng-repeat does its thing.

Here is the angular:

```
    (function(){

var app = angular.module("myReserveApp", []);

app.controller("ButtonController", ["$scope", "$window", function($scope, $window){
    $scope.buttonPress = function(){
        $window.alert(JSON.stringify($scope.car[0]));
    }

}]);

    var MainController = function($scope, $http, $window){

var onGatherBoatData = function(response){

    $scope.boat = response.data;

};

var onError = function(reason){

    $scope.error = "Could not fetch Boat Data";

};

var onGatherCarData = function(response){

    $scope.car = response.data;

};

var onError = function(reason){

    $scope.error = "Could not fetch Car Data";

};

var onGatherTruckData = function(response){

    $scope.truck = response.data;

};

var onError = function(reason){

    $scope.error = "Could not fetch Truck Data";

};



$scope.message = "Hello, Angular Here!";

    };

app.controller("MainController", ["$scope", "$http", "$window", MainController]);



    }());
```

Currently in the top portion of the code I just have it alerting object[0] but I want it to be specific to which button is pressed. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You can do `buttonPress($index)` in your HTML to pass in the index.

Comment: Just a quick remark: You could have easily found the answer to your question by doing a quick search here on Stackoverflow or consulting the AngularJS [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do the following, you can just pass the **current data** in the `ngRepeat`. Moreover,if you want the current index, the `ngRepeat` directive provide specials properties, as the `$index`, which is an iterator.

```
$scope.buttonPress = function(car, index){
      //Retrieve current data of the ngRepeat loop
      console.log(car);

      //Current index of your data into the array
      console.log(index);
  }
```

Then you can call your function like this :

```
<a  href="" ng-click="buttonPress(cars, $index)">Reserve</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

`$index` refers to the index in ng-repeat.  So if you want to pass your function the index in array on the button click, change `buttonPress()` to `buttonPress($index)`

you'll have to change your controller to something like the following:

```
$scope.buttonPress = function(index){
    $window.alert(JSON.stringify($scope.car[index]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, thank you both for the quick responses. Both of these answers work. I found another way to do it as well before reading your posts.

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <a  href="" ng-click="buttonPress(car.indexOf(cars))">Reserve:{{car.indexOf(cars)}}</a>
    </div>
```

Using (car.indexOf(cars)) gives me the same result

```
    $scope.buttonPress = function(index){
        $window.alert(JSON.stringify(index));   
    }
```

Now when I click on the "button" it sends me back the array index, so now I should be able to play with that data. Thank you again both, for your help.